# Compare stability points

Tags: potential-energy

If you are given the graph of two potential energy curves, with stability points, how do you compare these stability points to determine which one is more stable?

Comment: Locally the curve with the greatest curvature (smallest radius of curvature) is the most stable with respect to small displacements - meaning that the restoring force is greater..

Comment: Thanks! @sammy gerbil